# No module named crypto.PublicKey after installing cyrptodome through pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I am getting an error for the following import statement:

`from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA`

I keep on getting the error:
`no module named crypto.PublicKey.`

I have already installed pip3 and used it to install the following programs:
POS Packages:

```
jsonpickle
json5
Flask
Flask-Classful
p2pnetwork
requests
pycryptodome
pycrypto*
```

*pycrypto (installed after pycryptodome didn't work)

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: It's a bug not a rule. Once do : `from Crypto import PublicKey`, Then do the full thing. I think it's a pip bug or python bug. PLS respond after trying.

Comment: from Crypto import PublicKey
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

Is this what you want me to do? Because, it is still not working.

Comment: No just `from Crypto import PublicKey`  it's like u can't use all subs before u import parent once, thing is i had this problem and today had the same problem when i installed this library for first time, but it works now.